# MYSQL Code Not Pulling Info

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm writing my social network, and when a post is displayed on the newsfeed, the profile picture, and writer's name will not show. Here's my code:

```
$owner_id=mysql_result($result,$i,"post_owner_id"); //Post writer's user ID
$content=mysql_result($result,$i,"content"); //Content of the post
$date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date"); //Date
$time=mysql_result($result,$i,"time"); //Time
$poi_query=mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, profile_picture FROM users WHERE id = '" . $owner_id . "'"); //MYSQL query to get the information of the post writer using user ID
$post_firstname=mysql_result($poi_query, 0, "firstname"); //Writer's first name
$post_lastname=mysql_result($poi_query, 0, "lastname"); //Writer's Last name
$post_profile_picture=mysql_result($poi_query, 0, "profile_picture"); //Writer's profile picture
?>

      <div class="post">
        <h1 class="post-title"><a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $owner_id; ?>"> <?php echo $post_firstname; ?> <?php echo $post_lastname; ?></a></h1>
        <p class="content"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
        <p class="details"><?php echo $date; ?> at <?php echo $time; ?></p>
        <br/><hr/><br/>
      </div>
```

Everything else works perfectly fine besides the name and picture. Any help? I'm almost positive it has to do with the poi_query...
And by the way, all the code works fine in the terminal if I manually input the user ID's.

Config.inc:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';        // Your MySQL hostname. Usualy named as 'localhost', so you're NOT necessary to change this even this script has already online on the internet.
 $dbname   = 'social-network'; // Your database name.
 $username = 'root';             // Your database username.
 $password = '********';                 // Your database password. If your database has no password, leave it empty.

// Let's connect to host
 mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
 // Select the database
 mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

?>
```

Comment: Please post the line where you are including this config.inc file in your original PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

`$poi_query=mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, profile_picture FROM users WHERE id = '" . $owner_id . "'");`

to:

`$poi_query=mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, profile_picture FROM users WHERE id = '" . $owner_id . "'") or die(mysql_error());`

to see if you are receiving an error message about your query from MySQL.

EDIT:

The problem here ending up being a call `mysql_close();` that was interfering with the `$poi_query` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see, is maybe remove the quotes from the owner_id?

```
$poi_query=mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, profile_picture FROM users WHERE id = " . $owner_id);
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing out $owner_id, to make sure its not coming up blank?

Comment: @CassieCarter that is a good idea too, to make sure that `$owner_id` is what you expect it to be when you are feeding it into your query statement.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$poi_query=mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, profile_picture FROM users WHERE id = " . $owner_id) or die(mysql_error());
```

or try dumping the variable to see what it gives

```
var_dump($poi_query);
```

This will help you narrow down the problem